# What's the difference between (change) and (be changed)

Tags: grammar

If there are two sentences given to me:

> 1. I **can't do** it. (Can't + simple verb)
> 2. It **can't be changed** now. (Can't + be + past verb)

I'm not able to tell the difference in use. When do we use 1) or 2) ?

I took 2) from my book by the way, here's the full context:

> You've signed the contract. *It can't be changed now.*

and I'm still confused, why don't we use simple verb like: **it can't change now**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [something needs to change Or something needs to be changed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230788/something-needs-to-change-or-something-needs-to-be-changed)

Comment: @fev I've read it. So, does it mean **I can't change now** is also correct?

Comment: This question is nothing to do with ***can't***. It's entirely a matter of the difference between (active) ***changing*** and (passive) ***being changed***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I can't do it** is a sentence in the *active voice*. There is a thing that *I cannot do*.

**It can't be changed** is a sentence in the *passive voice*. There is a thing that *cannot be done to [an object]*.

Looking up "Active vs passive" will help you understand which one you should use when. In general, the active voice is used when you want to emphasize the person or thing doing the action, and the passive voice is used when you want to emphasize the action itself.

It would not be correct to use **You've signed the contract. It can't change now.** This is because the contract is an inanimate object; it could never change (itself). Instead, some *person* has to change the contract by crossing words out and writing new ones. **It can't be changed now** is the proper way of expressing the thought that the contract is set and unmodifiable. Another way to say it would be **You can't change it now**, but that leaves open the possibility that someone else might be able to change it; the original sentence means *no one* is able to change it.